# Hartl Tutorial Rails Flavored Ruby example with Ruby classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, initialization

```
class Word

  def palindrome?(string)
   string = string.reverse
  end
end
```

w=Word.new

w.palindrome?"level"

=> "level"

```
 class Word < String

  def palindrome?
   self == reverse
  end
end
```

w=Word.new("boxcar")

w.palindrome?

=> false

.....

What is the difference here? Why does the second example allow "boxcar" to be passed and the first example does not? Because the second inherits from String and it knows what a string is, where the first example doesnt? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the first example doesn't allow "boxcar"? It should. It, however, won't tell if it's a palindrome because you are using '=' (assignment) when you should be using '==' (equivalence).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mostly because of the String inheritance.
String.new() call a contructor method that sets the own instance of the class (self) as the value passed as a parameter.

The class Word, without the inheritance does not do this, unless you create a method initialize(param) by yourself.

When Word inherited from String, it also inherited its constructor method called `initialize()`. Whenever you create a new instance of one class, this method will be called by default.

Take a look at the initialize() definition on Rubi Docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/objinitialization.html

Answer (score 0):

```
w = Word.new
```

Your Word class does not define a method named new().

So your **first** Word class inherits Class#new(), which creates the object, then passes any arguments to Word's initialize() method.

Your Word class does not define an initialize() method, so ruby calls a dummy initialize() method in the C code, which is defined to take 0 arguments.

Your **second** Word class inherits String#new(), which is defined to take one argument, which is passed on to the C method rb_str_init() to create the String.